# Python - Pandas Drop Rows with strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In my dataset, I have a few rows which contain characters. 
I only need rows which contain all integers. What is the best possible way to do this? Below data set:
e.g I want to remove the rows 2nd and 3rd as they contain 051A, 04A, and 08B respectively.

```
1   2017    0   321     3   20  42  18
2   051A    0   321     3   5   69  04A
3   460     0   1633    16  38  17  08B
4   1811    0   822     8   13  65  18
```

Comment: Do you need to check for integers versus floats [and other non-string types]?

Comment: No, I was only looking for integers. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if apply can be avoided here

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors = 'coerce')).dropna()

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0   1   2017.0  0   321 3   20  42  18.0
3   4   1811.0  0   822 8   13  65  18.0
```

Comment: an option to avoid `apply`, though I not as good `pd.to_numeric(df.stack(), 'coerce').unstack().dropna()` (-:  That said, this doesn't address floats.  OP said rows of all ints.  If a float happened to be in a row, this would not drop it.

Answer (score 6):

This very similar to @jpp's solution but differs in the technique to check if digit.

```
df[df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).isdecimal()).all(1)].astype(int)

   0     1  2    3  4   5   6   7
0  1  2017  0  321  3  20  42  18
3  4  1811  0  822  8  13  65  18
```

Thanks to @jpp for suggesting `isdecimal` as opposed to `isdigit`

Comment: Since you mentioned isdecimal, that gave me an idea... not sure how fast it would be though.

Answer (score 5):

For this task, as stated, `try / except` is a solution which should deal with all cases.

[`pd.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap) applies a function to each element in the dataframe.

```
def CheckInt(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

res = df[df.applymap(CheckInt).all(axis=1)].astype(int)

#    0     1  2    3  4   5   6   7
# 0  1  2017  0  321  3  20  42  18
# 3  4  1811  0  822  8  13  65  18
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot!  `df[df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).isdigit()).all(1)].astype(int)`

Comment: `'1.1'.isdigit()` resolves to `False` for me.  Also, when I said I like "this" answer.  I meant yours (-:

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the other good answers, this solution uses the `stack` + `unstack` paradigm to avoid a loopy solution.

```
v = df.stack().astype(str)
v.where(v.str.isdecimal()).unstack().dropna().astype(int)

   0     1  2    3  4   5   6   7
0  1  2017  0  321  3  20  42  18
3  4  1811  0  822  8  13  65  18
```

Comment: This is definitely interesting though the problem with isdecimal is that it doesn't handle float. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

In one line, I think you can use `convert_objects` function from pandas. With this, we convert object to integer, which will result in NA. We finally drop na.

```
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dropna()
```

You can check more information here on [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html).