# Remove non-integer and non-float values from a column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset stored as a Pandas dataframe which contains income values of individuals. The responses include `integers`, `floats`, `strings` (e.g. 'Non-disclosed'), and `NaN`.

```
id, income
1,  120
2,  150.5
3,  Non-disclosed
4,  NaN
```

Is there a simple way to take only numerical rows so that the result is:

```
id, income
1,  120
2,  150.5
```

I don't mind the `integers` being converted to `floats`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Pandas Drop Rows with strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49203951/python-pandas-drop-rows-with-strings)

Comment: `df.assign(income=pd.to_numeric(df['income'], errors='coerce')).dropna()`

Comment: try with `pd.to_numeric(pd['income'], errors='coerce')`

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi this got it working, thank you very much. I was actually a bit unclear in my question, where there may be a third row containing all string values that I would not want to drop. I solved it by doing ```df['income'] = df['income'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors = 'coerce')).dropna()``` and then ```df[['income']].dropna()```